# Behavior when trying to change values of global and local const in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm learning C++ from past few days and when learning about the `const qualifier` tried the below:

```
const int m = 10;

int main()
{
    int* lptr;
    int* gptr;
    const int i = 20;
    lptr = (int *)&i;
    *lptr = 40; //line 1
    cout<<i<<endl;
    cout<<*lptr<<endl;

    *gptr = (int*)&m;
    *gptr = 50; //line 2
    cout<<m<<endl;
    cout<<*gptr<<endl;
}
```

Here, since I'm casting the `const int*` to `int*` explicitly, the code compilation is perfectly alright. In `line 1`, I'm surprised to see that there is no run time error(access violation). But in `line 2` there is a run time error saying `write access violation` (which is expected as const variables are placed in ro memory). But here why the local const variable is allowed to be modified through `lptr`. **Is there nothing like a read only memory on the stack also? (and if it doesn't then how safe is using const local variables as it can be modified with a pointer)**

***I'm using MSVC++ 14.0 ***

***I know that const variables are not meant to be modified, but since I'm leaning from basics I'm exploring the different ways***

Comment: Undefined behavior

Comment: C++11 reference: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.type.cv#4.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you can cast away const and then write to a const variable through a pointer to non-const does not make it legal. In fact it is undefined behaviour and your program is ill formed and has no meaning. The compiler is free to generate *whatever* code it feels like in that case.